# How to determine installed memory on x64 machine using visual studio windows 7

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, memory, ram, sysinfo

Is there a way to determine the amount of memory installed on a computer running
64bit windows 7, using VS2010 C?

The app I am running is a Windows 64bit app, with
a UI written in c#, which calls a dll written in C.  The call to get the installed
memory has to be done from the C code, not the c#.

Comment: VS3020?  Wow, I must be way behind the times.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Corrected VS2030 to VS2010.

Comment: Why must this be done in the C code? It's much easier using WMI from C#.

Comment: @Chimera Because the Windows API is written in C and C# merely calls the C code?

Comment: @Lundin No kidding the API is in C. My question is why must C be used when at least part of the application is already written in C# which provides easy access to WMI to provide system information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`GlobalMemoryStatusEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366589%28VS.85%29.aspx) function:

```
MEMORYSTATUSEX memInfo = {sizeof(memInfo)};
if (GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&memInfo))
{
    printf("Total installed physical memory: %lld bytes\n", memInfo.ullTotalPhys);
}
```